# lock-free synchronization, fences and memory order (store operation with acquire semantics)

Tags: c++11, atomic, lock-free, memory-fences, memory-barriers

I am migrating a project that was run on bare-bone to linux, and need to eliminate some `{disable,enable}_scheduler` calls. :)

So I need a lock-free sync solution in a single writer, multiple readers scenario, where the writer thread cannot be blocked. I came up with the following solution, which does not fit to the usual acquire-release ordering:

```
class RWSync {
    std::atomic<int> version; // incremented after every modification
    std::atomic_bool invalid; // true during write
public:
  RWSync() : version(0), invalid(0) {}
  template<typename F> void sync(F lambda) {
    int currentVersion;
    do {
      do { // wait until the object is valid
        currentVersion = version.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
      } while (invalid.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
      lambda();
      std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      // check if something changed
    } while (version.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != currentVersion
        || invalid.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
  }
  void beginWrite() {
    invalid.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  }
  void endWrite() {
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    version.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
    invalid.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
  }
}
```

I hope the intent is clear: I wrap the modification of a (non-atomic) payload between `beginWrite/endWrite`, and read the payload only inside the lambda function passed to `sync()`.

As you can see, here I have an atomic **store** in `beginWrite()` where no writes after the store operation can be reordered before the store. I did not find suitable examples, and I am not experienced in this field at all, so I'd like some confirmation that it is OK (verification through testing is not easy either).

1. Is this code race-free and work as I expect?
2. If I use std::memory_order_seq_cst in every atomic operation, can I omit the fences? (Even if yes, I guess the performance would be worse)
3. Can I drop the fence in endWrite()?
4. Can I use memory_order_acq_rel in the fences? I don't really get the difference -- the single total order concept is not clear to me.
5. Is there any simplification / optimization opportunity?

+1. I happily accept any better idea as the name of this class :)

Comment: As a suggestion: for me, working with such kind of problems was greatly simplified by using Relacy Race Detector. Classical tools like SPIN/Promela doesn't have direct support of advanced memory models.

https://github.com/dvyukov/relacy

Comment: Your code is broken: If the writer happens to execute `endWrite()` between the reader performing the `version.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != currentVersion)` and the `invalid.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` conditions, the reader won't see a version bump or a raised invalid flag, even though its code ran concurrent to the writer code. The writer might have called `beginWrite()` as early as the reader finishing the wait loop on the invalid flag in this scenario, clearly breaking the consistency of the read data.

Comment: You are right. What if I change the order of tests in do..while() condition, and check for invalid first, and version second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is basically correct.

Instead of having two atomic variables (`version` and `invalid`) you may use **single** `version` variable with semantic "Odd values are invalid". This is known as "sequential lock" mechanism.

Reducing number of atomic variables simplifies things a lot:

```
class RWSync {
    // Incremented before and after every modification.
    // Odd values mean that object in invalid state.
    std::atomic<int> version; 
public:
  RWSync() : version(0) {}
  template<typename F> void sync(F lambda) {
    int currentVersion;
    do {
      currentVersion = version.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      // This may reduce calls to lambda(), nothing more
      if(currentVersion | 1) continue;

      lambda();

      // Repeat until something changed or object is in an invalid state.
    } while ((currentVersion | 1) ||
        version.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) != currentVersion));
  }
  void beginWrite() {
    // Writer may read version with relaxed memory order
    currentVersion = version.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    // Invalidation requires sequential order
    version.store(currentVersion + 1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  }
  void endWrite() {
    // Writer may read version with relaxed memory order
    currentVersion = version.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    // Release order is sufficient for mark an object as valid
    version.store(currentVersion + 1, std::memory_order_release);
  }
};
```

Note the difference in memory orders in `beginWrite()` and `endWrite()`:

- `endWrite()` makes sure that all **previous** object's modifications have been completed. It is sufficient to use *release* memory order for that.
- `beginWrite()` makes sure that reader will detect object being in invalid state before any **futher** object's modification is started. Such garantee requires *seq_cst* memory order. Because of that reader uses *seq_cst* memory order too.

As for fences, it is better to incorporate them into previous/futher atomic operation: compiler knows how to make the result fast.

---

Explanations of some modifications of original code:

1) *Atomic modification* like `fetch_add()` is intended for cases, when **concurrent modifications** (like another `fetch_add()`) are possible. For correctness, such modifications use *memory locking* or other **very time-costly** architecture-specific things.

*Atomic assignment* (`store()`) does not use memory locking, so it is **cheaper** than `fetch_add()`. You may use such assignment because concurrent modifications are not possible in your case (reader does not modify `version`).

2) Unlike to *release-acquire* semantic, which differentiate `load` and `store` operations, sequential consistency (`memory_order_seq_cst`) is applicable to every atomic access, and provide total order between these accesses.

Comment: No, the code given by the OP is not correct. See my comment on the question.

Comment: Your code is correct, though, since it eliminates the race between checking the version and the invalidity flag.

Comment: Thanks for the correct implementation! Some questions:

Comment: 1) Why do you use separate load/store instead of fetch_add()?  

2) I used fences because I interpreted the documentation that a store() never can be an acquire operation, because that is applicable only for load operations. I guess this is what seq_cst comes into picture; so in this case even acq_rel would not be enough in beginWrite() and sync()?

Comment: 1) See edit of the answer. 2) Memory order `seq_cst` may be used for `store()` too, see edit of the answer. `acq_rel` semantic isn't applicable for `beginWrite()`, because it can only order events **previous** to the `store()`. As for *fences*, in your case they add nothing more than atomic operations with the same memory order.

Comment: @cmaster, I have realized that your solution permits the code in sync and in the writer thread run concurrently. Independent of that the sync runs in a spinning loop checking valid conditions, let alone accessing variables concurrently from two threads is an undefined behavior in c++11. :(

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct. I guess the code should be something like "currentVersion & 1" instead of "currentVersion | 1". And subtler mistake is that, reader thread can go into lambda(), and after that, the write thread could run beginWrite() and write value to non-atomic variable. In this situation, write action in payload and read action in payload haven't happens-before relationship. concurrent access (without happens-before relationship) to non-atomic variable is a data race. Note that, single total order of memory_order_seq_cst does not means the happens-before relationship; they are consistent, but two kind of things.